# button in expandable listview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have a ExpandableListActivity with an custom Adapter.

if the custom row of the adapter contains a imageViewall is done, but if i change this view from imageView to imageButton, the expandable listview don't expand.

Is there any method to put a button that can be clicked and the expandablelist does not lose the functionality to expand?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The button should be no-focuseable. In your  listView.setOnItemClickListener (not in xml layout!!) :

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourButton); 
//where button is the button on listView, and view is the view of your item on list

button.setFocusable(false);   /// THIS IS THE SOLUTION

button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //button functionalty   ...
    }
});
```

Comment: (Buttom) should be (Button)

Comment: yet another wtf moment for android

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you any explanation about this behaviour? It looks unrelated with the expand functionality from my point of view...

Comment: in my case I have a ScrollView and has the same behaviour in a ListView .. when visible the OnItemClickListener of the list don't work anymore (maybe focus problem, or double scroll problem ... not clear)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'focusable' attribute not just in the class, but in the xml as well, at least it's working for me.

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```