# Android:Not able to select Custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm using cursor adapter to get a custom list view.I've two xml files.

a.xml has a `Linearlayout` with `Listview`

y.xml has `Linearlayout` with two `Textview`.

I'm not able to select when i see a list view.I'm using `setOnItemClickListener` to select an item from list view.

I tried to search for this and came to know that many of them have the same issue.I tried applying this to both textview `android:focusable="false` in xml and programatically.

What is the fix for this issue?

**a.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**y.xml**

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where are you adding your onClick listener?

Comment: We need to see the XML and your java code to be able to help, otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: @Barak:Updated xml to my question.

Comment: @fasheikh:I'm not using onclick listener,instead using setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: ok, where are you defining that? if you could post your java please

Comment: @fasheikh:I'm defining setOnitemClickListener inside oncreate() method.after setting adapter to list view in the next line,i use listview.setOnitemClickListner.

Comment: are you able to see the list?

Comment: @fasheikh:I'm able to see the list but not able to select,i mean when you click you see a orange color glowing on list which indicates that item was selected.

Comment: ok so everything seems to be working ok but the listener, could you please post your java? if it's a problem, then change the class names etc

Comment: @fasheikh:textview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
     long id) {   } });

Comment: @fasheikh:I'm listing all my data in two text view.See my xml,you'ii under stand better.

Comment: you need to set the onItemClickListener to the listView

Comment: @fasheikh:I've mentioned it there wrongly but i'm doing that correctly in my code.

Comment: @fasheikh:When i put a log inside setOnitemClickListener,it is not showing in DDMS,that means it is not only getting called.I'm sure some problem with my xml.YOu do not need setOnitemclicklistenr only w/o this,if you click you can see the selcted item.

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `<scrollview>` ,it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem is like this: [button in expandable listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880950/button-in-expandable-listview-android/9892402#9892402)

try whit this:

```
mTextView.setFocuseable(false);
```

in your .java class instead your xml.

Comment: :I do not have any button,it is textview.I'm using setOnItemClickListener method.Updated my xml too in my question FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and hopefully it should give you some pointers, unfortunately can't do much without seeing your whole java!:

```
public class CRUDonDB extends ListActivity {

private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Doe','John','UK',22);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Smith','Robert','UK',20);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Walton','Henry','UK',10);");

        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Country, Age FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " where Age >= 10 LIMIT 5", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                    String lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName"));
                    String country = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Country"));
                    int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                    results.add("" + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + country + " " +age);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

        lv
        .setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemListViewClickListener);


    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (sampleDB != null) 
            sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
            sampleDB.close();
    }
}

private final OnItemClickListener mOnItemListViewClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have chosen " +item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
};
};

}
```

Comment: :I'm using custom cursor adapter,override newview and bindview.

Comment: an example with a custom adapter, toggles a checkbox onClick

Comment: :You've not under stood my question.When i select a row from listview,m not able to see the selection.Normally when you click on a row from listview,you should see an orange color appearing which means that row is selected.

Comment: I have understood your question, and it's not necessarily orange that is the highlight colour:) it's very difficult to help you without your full java code. Therefore, I have supplied a code to a working sample, so that you can compare it to your code and hopefully spot your error.

Comment: :I do not have any check boxes,all i have are two textview,i'm talking values from databases putting each value in a textview.

Comment: You never mentioned anything about a database, your question is very brief so I am doing the best I can, this will allow you to do what you want, just change the adapter to your custom one.

Comment: :I've a db ,i'm pulling data fromn content provider,i'm able to display data too only problem is ,m not able to select a data from list view.Thanks for all efforts.

Comment: so that didn't help? why don't you give me a little more info so I can see if I can be more helpful

Comment: change your displayData to parent, then change String selected =(String) (lview.getItemAtPosition(position)); to String selected =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: @fasheokh:Nothing changed still,i'm not able to select.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16914/discussion-between-fasheikh-and-redasaw)