# Adding a button to Expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, button

I'm trying to add a delete button to the right of the group textview of my `expandable ListView`.

The button appears but the list no longer expands. Here is the code I used to add the button.
  part of my `list_group.xml` **the one holding the parent textview in my list**.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#FD0987" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gplus_gb"
    android:text ="@string/Delete"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Attached are images of before and after adding the button onto the xml. In the first one the  list expands in the second one after button is added it doesn't .

[image]

Comment: You don't need a button to have an expandablelistview expand, then entire parent view is 'clickable' thus expanding any child views. Why do you **want** to use a button? Do you have an onclick method for the button?

Comment: I want to use a button to delete that element in the parent from the db. It's a delete button. @LokiSinclair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this question and answer: [button in expandable listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880950/button-in-expandable-listview-android).

According to this, button should be no-focuseable.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to make user confirm delete. So, Use Alert Dialog directly instead,

```
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MyApp.this);
                builder.setTitle("Delete?");
               builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {



                        }
                        });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {    


//do something to delete file.

                                }
            .               });

                builder.show();
            }
        });
```